# need to develop a custom Remote Desktop Application in C#

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I need to develop a custom Remote Desktop application with many additions. My customer(IT Company) has 40 employees and all employees use Remote Desktop app to connect to their own  customers' servers to work. My customer says that if one of their employee quits the job, that employee should be blocked from connecting to their customers.

Is there any way to program such a program? Is there any COM objects or something else?

Comment: If the customers provide an IP and a username/pwd to access remote machines / terminal servers then there is no way to simply implement a block from the end of the IT company and so the point becomes moot. Without knowing exactly how the AD, the network and the security works between the IT company and the customers, any answer is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Wim Ombelets, this could easily be achieved if the server / username / password was pre-defined. Creating a login for the RDP application itself and having profiles set up containing the IP, username & password should do it.

Comment: @Telexx I'm well aware of that, but if this information is not provided by the OP, you should not assume anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search provided me with this. I'm sure you could look over this project and get some ideas.

But yes, it is possible.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

> My customer says that if one of their employee quits the job, that employee should be blocked from connecting to their customers

This could easily be achieved if the server / username / password was pre-defined. Creating a login for the RDP application itself and having profiles set up containing the IP, username & password should do it. It would have course be a little more complex than that, to ensure it is actually secure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're better off implementing better security measures than writing a horrendously complex app that may well introduce additional security issues (security is *really* hard). RDP requires permissions on the remote machine, so when an employee leaves, you should be able to remote into those machines and revoke those user accounts, no?

## Actually...

Aren't we missing the elephant in the room here? If you build a new client that has the ability for you to disable access for ex-employees, what's to stop them going home and using the normal RDP client?

This definitely needs to be a server-based fix, and I now more strongly than ever believe you should delete/deactivate ex-employees' accounts on the remote machines. You *are* using individual user accounts, aren't you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Desktop Sharing interfaces for the same or the ActiveX client. Check out this.

Active X : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33979/Multi-RDP-Client-NET

WDS : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373307(v=vs.85).aspx

Additionallly you can see:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET